# If statement: CGPoint returns strange value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint

I have an variable with the datatype CGPoint, named endPosition. When endPosition gets its value inside an if statement, it returns this crazy value: **End position: {1.6347776e-33, 1.4012985e-45}**.

**1. example:**

```
    if ([touch view] != background)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        CGPoint endPosition;

        if([touch view] == circle){
            CGPoint endPosition = {462.5, 98.5};
        }

        CGFloat xDist = (endPosition.x - location.x);
        CGFloat yDist = (endPosition.y - location.y);

        CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));

        NSLog(@"End Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(endPosition));
    }
```

When the CGPoint endPosition is not inside this if statement, i get the right value: **End position: {462.5, 98.5}**

**2. example:**

```
    if ([touch view] != background)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        CGPoint endPosition = {462.5, 98.5};

        CGFloat xDist = (endPosition.x - location.x);
        CGFloat yDist = (endPosition.y - location.y);

        CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));

        NSLog(@"End Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(endPosition));
     }
```

Can anyone tell me what to do? I need this if statement :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you entering the `if`?

Answer (score 4):

In your example 1, you never initialise the value of `endPosition`. That's because in the 'if' statement (`if([touch view] == circle){`) you are defining a new variable called `endPosition` which replaces the other one in that scope. You should probably initialise `endPosition` to `CGPointZero` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That's because in the first case you don't set a value for `endPoint` if `[touch view] != circle`.

In that case your variable is uninitialized and you get a random value that happens to be there in memory. You have to handle the other case (`else`) or initialize your variable to some value when you declare it, like `CGPointZero`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CGPoint endPosition; //This is a declaration of a of new stack variable of name "endPosition"

    if([touch view] == circle){
        CGPoint endPosition = {462.5, 98.5}; //...AND this is a declaration of another variable
    }
```

You want to remove CGPoint from the second line.

Additionally, since your CGPoint is never initialized it's not necessarily the case that it will have a non-garbage value.  You could add an else block and put endPosition = CGPointZero there or you could do that on the first line.

EDIT: Also {462.5, 98.5} is the wrong size (2 doubles), {462.5f, 98.5f} is 2 floats, but you should probably just stick to CGPointMake and avoid 'complex' literals.

Comment: Hi Ryan, It makes sense. But when i try to do it, like this:         CGPoint sp = CGPointZero;
        
     if([touch view] == circle){
      sp = {462.5, 98.5}; // Expected expression
        } I get this error expected expression?

Comment: Try turning {462.5, 98.5} into CGPointMake(462.5f, 98.5f)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    CGPoint endPosition = CGPointZero;

    if([touch view] == circle){
        endPosition = CGPointMake(462.5, 98.5);
    }
```